# Type used in a using statement must be explicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: entity-framework-6, devart

Using Entity Framework and Devart Entity Developer on an existing database. I brought the table needed into the Entity Designer model using the wizard. Saved the model - that creates the underlying code for EF. Now when I try to use:

```
using (Document ctx = new Document())
{

}
```

I get the error:

> CS1674    'Document': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' or implement a suitable 'Dispose' method.

I have seen posts that suggest that state to make sure that Entity Framework is added as a NuGet package - it is. I have use Entity Designer before in this situation but did not run into this issue.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Document:

```
public partial class Document : EntityObject    {//...
```

EntityObject:

```
namespace System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses
{
  /// <summary>
  /// This is the class is the basis for all perscribed EntityObject classes.
  /// </summary>
  [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
  [Serializable]
  public abstract class EntityObject : StructuralObject, IEntityWithKey, IEntityWithChangeTracker, IEntityWithRelationships
  {
```

Comment: Of what type is `Document`? That does not look like a context unless it is a devart class that inherits.

Comment: Document is a table named Document in the database.

Comment: @Steve Green: I did check another app that I used this from. The table objects inherit from ObjectContext rather than EntityObject

Comment: Where are you expecting the `IDisposable` implementation to come from? `EntityObject`  doesn't implement it and it doesn't look like `Document` does either.

Comment: You don't `use` a table - you `use` the context and then access the table like `context.Documents`.

Comment: Please send us a small test project for reproducing the error in our environment: https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.

Comment: @Steve Greene - You are correct. That was the issue - operator error. Thank you.